# Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestErrorInvalid Value [400] Errors Message[Invalid Value] Location Reason[invalid] Domain[global]

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

using this library `(Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1, ver. 1.32.2.1146, in .Net VS2017 c# framework 4.7.1, from nuget)`,
occasionally, I get the following error:

> ...the service *xxxxxx* has thrown an exception:
>   Google.GoogleApiException: 
>       Google.Apis.Requests.RequestErrorInvalid Value [400]
>       Errors [    Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]]
>          in Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest 1.d__34.MoveNext()
>          --- End the stack trace from the previous position where the exception was generated ---
>          in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   in
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest 1.Execute() in...

In most cases, everything works correctly, without any changes in the code.

Below the procedure used:

```
public DataTable RunSearch(string querySearch, string dateRestrict, string excludeTerms, string orTerms)
{
    string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gsApiKey"];
    string searchEngineIdCX = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gsCX"];

    DataTable dtRes = getDt(); // create a custom table

    try
    {
        var customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });
        var listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(querySearch);
        listRequest.Cx = searchEngineIdCX;
        listRequest.Googlehost = "google.it";
        listRequest.DateRestrict = dateRestrict; // "d1"
        listRequest.ExcludeTerms = excludeTerms;
        listRequest.OrTerms = orTerms;
        IList<Result> paging = new List<Result>();
        int count = 0;

        while (paging != null && dtRes.Rows.Count < 100)  // max 100 free
        {
            listRequest.Start = count * 10 + 1; // every query gets 10 Results
            paging = listRequest.Execute().Items; // Each lap is a query that scales from 100 available
            if (paging != null)
            { 
                foreach (var item in paging)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtRes.NewRow();
                    dr["Count"] = dtRes.Rows.Count + 1;
                    dr["Title"] = item.Title;
                    dr["Link"] = item.Link;
                    dr["Snippet"] = item.Snippet;
                    dtRes.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Google.GoogleApiException gex)
    {
        string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
        logger.Fatal(msgErr, gex);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
        logger.Fatal(msgErr, ex);
        throw;
    }

    return dtRes;
}
```

What may be the error that occurs?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Login Required \[401\] Message\[Login Required\] Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727352/google-apis-requests-requesterror-login-required-401-messagelogin-required-l)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Login Required 401 != Invalid Value [400].